# Enumerate the list of installed apps on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

Can we enumerate the installed apps on windows phone 8.1 or know if an app is installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **InstallationManager class**: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.management.deployment.installationmanager.aspx)
Use method **FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher** for enumerate all installed apps from current publisher on device.
For more capability you need receive permission from  Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed. You can launch another app, but there's no way of knowing which apps are installed.